# How to troubleshoot a Sagemaker Studio solution that doesn't launch?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Every time I try to launch a SageMaker Solution, the Studio keeps spinning and nothing happens, not even an error message. What am I possibly doing wrong? How can I collect information to troubleshoot the issue?

Steps to reproduce:

- with the console, log into the Europe (Paris) or U.S. East (N. Virginia)
- go to SageMaker
- ensure Quick setup is selected
- create a new role, keep the defaults except select "Any S3 bucket"
- create a user profile with the new role
- once the profile is ready, use it to launch the Studio
- in the Studio, go to JumpStart
- select the "Fraud Detection in Financial Transactions using Deep Graph Library" solution and try to Launch it
- the studio just keeps spinning, the solution is not launched

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you just recently and I can tell you I solved it by recreating the [Amazon SageMaker Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-studio-onboard.html) with the **Standard setup** configuration (so, not Quick setup).

Inside it you have to specify all the correct configurations such as IAM entries, VPC / security groups and all information blocking the display of Studio resources.

In the quick, in fact, they are not asked and you run into this problem you show.

To **delete the domain and recreate a new one**, it is necessary to:

- Delete all jupyter server apps
- Delete all user profiles
- Delete the domain